# CSS alignment of date, amount and total

Tags: css

Want to align the text in the 3 rows on the right to be right justified on the far right column: amounts / entries and same font size as the description text on the left column (i have set to 20 but content of input field remains small), and to evenly make the 3 rows the same height.

Don't want fields to appear as input fields just text.

- keeping the Red and Blue boxes unchanged.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 4;
}

#look {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  align-self: center;
}

.space {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#customer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: 140px;
}

#address-title {
  width: 450px;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  background: blue;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#address-one {
  width: 450px;
  height: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#meta {
  align-self: flex-end;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

td:first-child {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="customer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="space"></div>
    <textarea form="testinsert" name="address" id="address-title">Customer Invoices</textarea>
    <textarea form="testinsert" name="address1" id="address-one"></textarea>
  </div>

  <img src="images/green-plus.png" class="lookup-cust-plus" id="look" />

  <table id="meta">
    <tr>
      <td class="meta-head">Invoice #</td>
      <td><textarea form="testinsert" id="invoice_num" name="invoice">20170212</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td form="testinsert" name="date" class="meta-head">Date</td>
      <td><textarea id="date">February 12, 1965</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="meta-head">Amount Due</td>
      <td>
        <div class="due">$0.00</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you want, can you explain a bit more clearly?

Comment: want the table with invoice, amount and amount due to be the same height as the red and blue boxes 100px and need the three rows to fill that height with right justification on col 2 and left on col 1

Comment: Do you have a design of what it should look like?

Comment: i've got most of it figured out - just trying to get border as single line not double? I don't know what the 'flex' lines are doing - code is from another source. look at: https://jsfiddle.net/jeffbarclay/xt10nr7e/33/

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure, but here's the modified css (you can copy/paste it to your jsfiddle to check):

```
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#customer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  order:1;
  flex-direction: column;

}

#look {
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
  align-self: center;
}

.space {
  flex-grow: 1;
}



#address-title {
  width: 450px;
  height: 20px;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: blue;
  display:flex;
}

img{order:2;}

#address-one {
  display:flex;
  width: 450px;
  height: 80px;
  min-height: 80px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: red;
}

#meta {
   align-self:flex-end;
   order:3;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}

td:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: green;
  width: 180px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

And to answer the question to what flex does: it distributes equally space for blocks,without knowing their widths. For a more in depth documentation, I'd recommend css tricks guide: [csstricks guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Hope it helps, and good luck.